# Is there any way to display the WooCommerce mini-cart on my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm developing a website whereby I would like customers to be able to constantly view the contents of their cart so they can add/remove items on the fly (using WooCommerce).

The theme I'm currently using is Flatsome (with the UXBuilder)

I've noticed there is a template for the WooCommerce mini-cart in woocommerce/templates/mini-cart.php. This looks like what I want to be displayed on my page

I have a plugin called WooCommerce Product Tables that (I believe) displays this  mini-cart [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaWGM.png)

I was wondering if there is any way for me to display this as a fixed element (within a div perhaps) on my page?

I'm quite inexperienced, so any help is appreciated :)

Comment: check out https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-fly-cart/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Create the shortcode in `functions.php`

```php
// Add Shortcode
function custom_mini_cart() { 
    echo '<a href="#" class="dropdown-back" data-toggle="dropdown"> ';
        echo '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        echo '<div class="basket-item-count" style="display: inline;">';
            echo '<span class="cart-items-count count">';
                echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
            echo '</span>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mini-cart">';
        echo '<li>';
            echo '<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">';
                woocommerce_mini_cart();
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_techno_mini_cart', 'custom_mini_cart' );
```

2. Then add this `[custom_techno_mini_cart]` shortcode anywhere on page.
3. Now add this inside your template:

```php
<?php echo do_shortcode('[custom_techno_mini_cart]'); ?>
```

4. Make your layout according to your requirement in first point.
5. Add like this also using this

```php
woocommerce_mini_cart()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This has worked well so far, just have to figure out how to style it to my needs :)

Comment: in theme style.css just add the class or id of div,a like eg. For this <a href="#" class="dropdown-back" data-toggle="dropdown"> in my post 

  .dropdown-back{border:2px solid black;} just something like that.

Comment: Where did you add the shortcode?I also have a similar problem @VabihavKumar

Comment: When deleting item from mini cart it does not decrease count of cart. Is there any thing to do so?

Answer (score 20):

As **Bhoomi** suggested, using `woocommerce_mini_cart();` works however ajax cart doesn't update the minit cart.

Using this method I suggest to wrap mini_cart function with "widget_shopping_cart_content" woocommerce class, for example :

```
<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content"><?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?></div>
```

So with ajax add to cart, the mini cart is updated also.

Comment: Where did you add the shortcode?I also have a similar problem

Comment: @Snow  it will go to the functions.php file

Answer (score 12):

You can use `woocommerce_mini_cart()` wherever you want to display your minicart.

This function loads the mini-cart.php template to display the mini cart.